# Iterate over array of queries and append results to object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to return results from two database queries in one object.

```
function route(start, end) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const queries = routeQuery(start, end);
        var empty_obj = new Array();
        for (i=0; i<queries.length; i++) {
            query(queries[i], (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject('query error', err);
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                empty_obj.push(res.rows);
            }});
        }
        console.log(empty_obj);
        resolve({coords: empty_obj});
    });
}
```

This is my code right now, the queries are working fine but for some reason, pushing each result into an empty array does not work. When I console log that empty object, it stays empty. The goal is to resolve the promise with the generated object containing the two query results. I'm using node-postgres for the queries.

Output of res is an object:

```
{
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 18,
  oid: null,
  rows: [
    { ...
```

Comment: What is the console output of res?

Comment: Can you give example your array or data

Comment: the callback is asynchronuos.  resolve will be called before empty_obj is ready.  you should be pushing an array of  Promises to feed to Promise.all or rearrange your callback chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you turn your `query` function into a `Promise` so that you can use `Promise.all`:

```js
// turn the callback-style asynchronous function into a `Promise`
function queryAsPromise(arg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    query(arg, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

Then, you could do the following in your `route` function:

```js
function route(start, end) {
  const queries = routeQuery(start, end);

  // use `Promise.all` to resolve with 
  // an array of results from queries
  return Promise.all(
    queries.map(query => queryAsPromise(query))
  )
  // use `Array.reduce` w/ destructing assignment 
  // to combine results from queries into a single array
  .then(results => results.reduce(
    (acc, item) => [...acc, ...item.rows],
    []
  ))
  // return an object with the `coords` property
  // that contains the final array
  .then(coords => {
    return { coords };
  });
}

route(1, 10)
  .then(result => {
    // { coords: [...] }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle errors appropriately
    console.error(error);
  });
```

References:

- [Promise.all - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Array.reduce - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Destructing assignment - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you currently face is due to the fact that:

```
resolve({coords: empty_obj});
```

Is not inside the callback. So the promise resolves before the query callbacks are called and the rows are pushed to `empty_obj`. You could move this into the `query` callback in the following manner:

```
empty_obj.push(res.rows); // already present
if (empty_obj.length == queries.length) resolve({coords: empty_obj});
```

This would resolve the promises when all rows are pushed, but leaves you with another issue. Callbacks might not be called in order. Meaning that the resulting order might not match the `queries` order.

The easiest way to solve this issue is to convert each individual callback to a promise. Then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until all promises are resolved. The resulting array will have the data in the same order.

```
function route(start, end)
  const toPromise = queryText => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    query(queryText, (error, response) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(response));
  });

  return Promise.all(routeQuery(start, end).map(toPromise))
         .then(responses => ({coords: responses.map(response => response.rows)}))
         .catch(error => {
           console.error(error);
           throw error;
         });
}
```